# SQLite library for .net Core/Standard: MS EF or sqlite.org?

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, .net-standard, system.data.sqlite, .net-standard-2.0

I'm having trouble getting a overview of the different SQLite libraries to be used with .Net Core and/or Standard.
It seems there are primarily two:

- MS: [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/index)
- sqlite.org: [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org)

Is the MS library completely independent of the sqlite.org's libraries? And if so, which one is recommended to use?
I prefer simplicity....it seems I just need two dll's if using sqlite.org.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main SQLite packages for .NET Core/Standard. They are independent and use separate native binaries.

- Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
- System.Data.SQLite

The former is provided by Microsoft, the latter by SQLite.org. I prefer the Microsoft one but unless you're looking for specific functionality (SQLite.org's supports encryption, Microsoft's supports fts5, etc) either one will probably work fine. They both implement System.Data.Common and so the APIs are almost identical. SQLite.org's can load arbitrary extensions which Microsoft's cannot (though with the latest release it was looking like SQLite.org's couldn't load fts5 which I know worked with previous releases).

I would recommend using Entity Framework Core or another similar third-party database abstraction package unless you absolutely can't use modelling for some reason (EFCore still lets you run the occasional low level query if you need to). It's quicker to develop, and easier to maintain the code.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite provides support for Sqlite in EFCore, using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite. So you would want to use that in this case. The internet says you can also use System.Data.SQLite but it looks like Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite still tries to load the underlying native binary from Microsoft.Data.Sqlite for some purpose, though it does appear to use System.Data.SQLite for the actual database operations. Not sure exactly what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite is for Entity Framework Core ORM is more complete but heavier.

The System.Data.SQLite.Core can use with [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) [SQLite and Dapper](https://richardniemand.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/sqlite-and-dapper-in-c/) but I use the [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/) with [SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3/) and [Dapper ORM](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), I think I had problems with System.Data.SQLite.Core.

Use without is hard and I not recommend.

Comment: What is `System.Data.SQLite.Core`?, it seem to be just a nuget package and not a library itself, right?  If I look into the nuget package I only find the `System.Data.SQLite.dll`, which I assume is a .Net Standard wrapper for the unmanaged/native library `SQLite.Interop.dll`, right?

Comment: And `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core`is just a wrapper for the `SQLitePCL.raw` library, right? Why use that over `SQLite.Interop.dll`? I assume which wrapper you use means less, the real work is done by the unmanage/native library.

Comment: I THINK if there is a .Core and a  non .Core package, the non-.Core usually includes the .Core and other packages, and it serves to bundle all the packages up into one unit you can install, and the versions are maintained. I believe .Core is supposed to include actual code and other content for the top-level functionality. They existed before .NET Core was a thing so the naming is just unfortunate.